# vertrigo 229 in not working on windows 8

Tags: http, localhost

today i installed vertrigo 229 on windows 8 and it is not working
it shows the message that

"Apache HTTP server does not work correctly. Check whether other applications use the server port(usually 80) and terminate them.Moreover, check firewall setting and correctness the configuration files."

and it do not even open localhost
what should i do?

Answer (score 4):

Try to run Vertrigo as Administrator. Then, you will be able to access the localhost through the 8080 port (127.0.0.1:8080). To change that edit the following line in c:\program files\vertrigo serv\apache\conf\httpd.conf (Ensure to run the text editor as Administrator):

Listen 8080

to

Listen 80

Now you should be able to access the localhost.

Answer (score 0):

If running Vertrigo as Administrator doesn't work, check your Apache configuration carefully.

I had this problem after transferring my Apache settings to a new computer and the problem turned out to be in a single VirtualHost directive where the DocumentRoot pointed at a directory that didn't exist on my new machine. Removing this VirtualHost and then restarting Vertrigo fixed the problem.

```
<VirtualHost *> 
    ServerName somesite.dev
    DocumentRoot "c:/www/non/existent/directory"
</VirtualHost>
```